# Showing that $q=(z_1,z_2^2)$ is primary in $\mathcal O_2 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, power-series, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

1. Show that if $q$ is primary, then $\sqrt{q}$ is prime.
2. Show that in the ring $\mathcal O_2 = \mathbb C\{z_1, z_2\}$, $q=(z_1,z_2^2)$ is primary.

[original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyFic.jpg)

I already did the first item. For the second, I tried writing two power series with variables $z_1$ and $z_2$, but I couldn't show how the product of them is a member of the ideal generated by $z_1, z_2^2$ (in fact, I don't know how can I re-write the series).

Again, I ONLY need help on the item $(2)$, and this is all that I did. I think this might be an easy problem, but I'm really stucked at this.

Comment: Is that notation you have for power series rings? I always associated $\mathcal O$ with rings of integers, and I haven't seen braces used for power series rings...

Comment: Well, in the book that means the set of germs of holomorphic functions. Then, it says that we can identify that set with set of power series which converge absolutely in some neighborhood of zero.

Comment: OK cool. Now I understand a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that, by definition, the ideal $\sqrt{q} =${$x \in R / x^n \in q$ for some $n$}.
It implies that, if $q$ is primary, for any product $ab \in \sqrt{q}$ you have that $a \in \sqrt{q}$ or $b \in \sqrt{q}$, because, for some $n$, $a^n \in q$ or $b^n \in q$, and that is the definition of being prime. There is no need of using power series. Just write down the definitions and go on with them!

For the second item, it is enough to show that every zero divisor in $C\{z_1,z_2^2\}/(q)$ is nilpotent, which implies that q is primary.

Good luck!

Comment: But this is the answer for the first item, I already did that. I'm talking about the second one, and then I'll need power series because, if I'm right, they are the elements of $\mathbb{C}$ {$z_1,z_2$}.

Comment: Yes, I already edited the answer and suggested the way to prove the second item, excuse me

Comment: Yeah, but that's the definition of primary, that I know. The book says that I can show that $ab \in q \rightarrow a \in q$ or $b^k \in q$. The problem is: choosing two elements of the ideal and writing the product of them, since the elements of $\mathbb{C}$ {$z_1,z_2$} are power series. The product is very 'large' and rewriting that as en element of $q$ apparently is not the best way of solving this.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm suggesting to prove that every zero divisor in the ring I wrote is nilpotent, which is less cumbersome than write down the products.

Comment: Well, I think I'm not being very clear. That suggestion is equivalente of what I told you that the book says. When I start the demonstration, I'm not seeing how I can write $xy=az_1+bz_2$, and then concludes that $x \in q$ or $y^k \in q$. I think that my notation is wrong, or that this don't make much sense. I know the steps, but taking the first step is what I'm finding difficult. I don't see how doing that is making this easier, since I'm not being able to move to next step like this.